# How to assigned values from firebase in functional compoent react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, functional-programming, components

i am new to react and firebase.

***PROBLEM:***

I am trying to access a variable which returns true when it successfully gets the result, it is working inside .then method, but outside then method cannot get the result (isStudent variable). is there any way of retrieving and assigning in this functional component,instead of making it as class component.
 any suggestions, hints would be helpful.

```
  const Routes = props => {
                  if (props.user) {
                     let isStudent=false;

                    const uid = props.user.uid;

                    firebase
                      .database()
                      .ref(`student/${uid}`)
                      .once("value")
                      .then(snapshot => {
                        if (snapshot.val().role === "student") {
                          console.log(snapshot.val());
                            isStudent=true
                        }
                      });

                    console.log(isStudent); //false
//i am getting the default value, if i remove that i get undefined

                  return (
                    <MainLayout>
                      <Switch>

                <StudentPublicRoute
                          {...props}
                          exact
                          restricted={true}
                          path="/student/login"
                          component={StudentLogin}
                        />
                        {isStudent&& <StudentPrivateRoute
                          {...props}
                          path="/student/studentdashboard"
                          exact
                          component={StudentDash}
                        />}
                 </Switch>
                    </MainLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your code, `console.log(isStudent);` is executed before the code

```
snapshot => {
          if (snapshot.val().role === "student") {
          console.log(snapshot.val());
          isStudent=true
        }
```

is executed, so you will get `isStudent=false`

so you can use `async-await`

```
  const Routes = async props => {
                  if (props.user) {
                  let isStudent=false;

                  const uid = props.user.uid;

                  const studentRef = await firebase
                          .database()
                          .ref(`student/${uid}`);
                  const studentSnapshot = await studentRef.once('value');

                  if (studentSnapshot.val().role === "student") {
                      isStudent=true;
                  }                      

                  console.log(isStudent); 

                  return (
                        <MainLayout>
                          <Switch>
                            <StudentPublicRoute
                                      {...props}
                                      exact
                                      restricted={true}
                                      path="/student/login"
                                      component={StudentLogin}
                                    />
                                    {isStudent&& <StudentPrivateRoute
                                      {...props}
                                      path="/student/studentdashboard"
                                      exact
                                      component={StudentDash}
                                    />}
                             </Switch>
                        </MainLayout>
```